# Merging files on the basis of columns

Tags: r, merge

I have multiple files with many rows and three columns and need to merge them on the basis of first two columns match. File1

```
12   13   a
13   15   b
14   17   c
 4    9   d
 .    .   .
 .    .   .
 81   23  h
```

File 2

```
12   13   e
3    10   b
14   17   c
 4    9   j
 .    .   .
 .    .   .
 1   2    k
```

File 3

```
12   13   m
13   15   k
1     7   x
24    9   d
 .    .   .
 .    .   .
 1   2    h
```

and so on.
I want to merge them to obtain the following result

```
12   13   a  e  m
13   15   b  k
14   17   c  c
 4    9   d  j
 3   10   b
24    9   d
 .    .   .
 .    .   .
 81   23  h
  1    2  k
  1    7  x
```

Comment: have you tried `merge` ... ??

Comment: See the following post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: You might look at dplyr and its join capabilities.

Comment: @BenBolker, I'm not sure if `merge` is the best option for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that usually comes to mind with these types of problems is `merge`, perhaps in conjunction with a `Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "somecols", all = TRUE), yourListOfDataFrames)`.

However, `merge` is not always the most efficient function, especially since it looks like you want to "collapse" all the values to fill in the rows from left to right, which would not be the default `merge` behavior.

Instead, I suggest you stack everything into one long `data.frame` and reshape it after you have added an index variable.

Here are two approaches:

### Option 1: "dplyr" + "tidyr"

1. Use `mget` to put all of your `data.frame`s into a `list`.
2. Use `rbind_all` to convert that `list` into a single `data.frame`.
3. Use `sequence(n())` in `mutate` from "dplyr" to group the data and create an index.
4. Use `spread` from "tidyr" to transform from a "long" format to a "wide" format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

combined <- rbind_all(mget(ls(pattern = "^file\\d")))
combined %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>% 
  mutate(time = sequence(n())) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(time, V3, fill = "")
# Source: local data frame [7 x 5]
# 
#   V1 V2 1 2 3
# 1  1  7 x    
# 2  3 10 b    
# 3  4  9 d j  
# 4 12 13 a e m
# 5 13 15 b k  
# 6 14 17 c c  
# 7 24  9 d
```

### Option 2: "data.table"

1. Use `mget` to put all of your `data.frame`s into a `list`.
2. Use `rbindlist` to convert that list into a single `data.table`.
3. Use `sequence(.N)` to generate your sequence by your groups.
4. Use `dcast.data.table` to convert the "long" `data.table` into a "wide" one.

```
library(data.table)

dcast.data.table(
  rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "^file\\d")))[, 
    time := sequence(.N), by = list(V1, V2)],
  V1 + V2 ~ time, value.var = "V3", fill = "")
#    V1 V2 1 2 3
# 1:  1  7 x    
# 2:  3 10 b    
# 3:  4  9 d j  
# 4: 12 13 a e m
# 5: 13 15 b k  
# 6: 14 17 c c  
# 7: 24  9 d
```

---

Both of these answers assume we are starting with the following sample data:

```
file1 <- structure(
  list(V1 = c(12L, 13L, 14L, 4L), V2 = c(13L, 15L, 17L, 9L), 
       V3 = c("a", "b", "c", "d")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
file2 <- structure(
  list(V1 = c(12L, 3L, 14L, 4L), V2 = c(13L, 10L, 17L, 9L), 
       V3 = c("e", "b", "c", "j")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
file3 <- structure(
  list(V1 = c(12L, 13L, 1L, 24L), V2 = c(13L, 15L, 7L, 9L), 
       V3 = c("m", "k", "x", "d")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```